# Get only a portion of the response from using the .load command

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

All,
I'm using Wordpress and I have a lot of code in a shortcode to display my blogs in a certain layout. I'm also using the isotope plugin and I'm also using the infinite scroll plugin as well.

The infinite scroll uses the a destination URL which I traced to be using this code:

```
instance._debug('Using HTML via .load() method');
box.load(desturl + ' ' + opts.itemSelector, undefined, function infscr_ajax_callback(responseText) {
    instance._loadcallback(box, responseText, desturl);
});
```

For them this works great and only loads the content that I want it to which is basically only the content which is basically only data in divs with a class of "post". There is usually definitely more then one div with a class of post that would get returned each time as well. I want to use .load because the code to display the content in the post is a lot and I don't want to repeat that with ajax.

How can I only display a portion of what was returned by the load function?

I tried to do the following:

```
var desturl = 'http://localhost:1234/vendor_new/display-vendor-results/page/1/?category_id=' + selector + '/';
    $( ".vendor_change_container" ).load( desturl + " .type-post", function( response, status, xhr ) {
        alert(status);
        alert(response);
        if ( status == "error" ) {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            alert(msg);
            $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
        }
    });
```

Nothing gets updated in my change container class. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? The function is returning success and is also returning the html but nothing gets displayed. In my console I see a message `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'`

This shouldn't matter since I'm just trying to return only the divs with a post.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I've fully understood your question, did you look at the documentation for jQuery .load(), in particular [Loading Page Fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)? Do you want to "cache" the returned results and add to the div from the resultset?

Comment: @jammykam That looks to be on the right track. I don't need to cache it, just get the results from inside the divs with a post. I updated my question with what I tried to do.

Comment: There should be no comma, try `$( ".change_container" ).load( desturl + " .post" )`

Comment: @jammykam I realized that. I updated the question again. It's showing success oddly enough.

Comment: You need a space before `.post` now :) So " .post"

Comment: @jammykam Realized that too :) I also tried to do something more specific and changed it to type-post and still nothing.

Comment: If you are using `$( ".vendor_change_container" ).load( desturl + " .post")` then script tags should be striped out from the response according to the docs. Updated your question with the exact code again (with spaces, dots etc). Also check with "console.log(response)" after success (in dev tools[F12])

Comment: @jammykam I updated it with exactly how I'm trying to do it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41588/discussion-between-jammykam-and-user1048676)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I've fully understood your question, did you look at the documentation for jQuery .load(), in particular [Loading Page Fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)? Do you want to "cache" the returned results and add to the div from the resultset?

You should just be able to insert your posts by:

```
$(box).load(desturl + ' ' + opts.itemSelector);
```

I assume opts.itemSelector equates to `.posts` to filter out the elements you need. Otherwise:

```
$(box).load(desturl + ' .posts');
```